# Adding 3D buildings in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

i was working on google maps v2 android app and i worked on adding custom map tiles but my question is : is there any possiable way that i can add 3d Building model over my custom map tile and use it in the app so users can view the building in my app in 3d view ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible using true 3d, you might be able to come up with some clever ways using an iso projection, but it will be a little iffy. Just being able to sync the camera and the projection of your view without access to the gl context would be almost not possible in my mind. If this could be done this would be awesome.

Comment: sorry for being late to say thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Using google maps we can able to add google maps 3d view by adding this line

```
mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
```

Eg:

And set the *zoom level to 20* so that you can able to see the Buildings in 3d.

```
// Construct a *CameraPosition* focusing on Mountain View and animate the camera to that position.

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
              .target(SYDNEY)      
              .zoom(21).bearing(67).tilt(45).build();                   

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

For your Reference

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views